# How to use Selenium Chromdriver on Android

Tags: python, android, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, kivy

I've written a very simple script within kivy using selenium.

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from selenium import webdriver

class KivyButton(App):
    def update(self,instance,*args):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get('https://google.com')
    def build(self):
        self.layout  = FloatLayout(size=(300,300))
        self.mybtn=Button(text='Enter',on_press=self.update,pos=(500,300),size_hint=(.1,.1))
        self.layout.add_widget(self.mybtn)
        return self.layout

KivyButton().run()
```

It's basically just a button that when you click it, takes you to google. I'm using buildozer to convert/run this on my phone. I've set the dependencies as python,kivy, selenium,chromedriver,urllib3. It then pip installs these dependencies. The app will load, but this is the output when I try to run selenium.

```
python : PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission Denied
```

From looking online, this error appears to pop up when chromedriver is not configured properly. Using this site: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started/getting-started---android it states chromedriver should work for android chrome, but in their example they use `'./chromedriver'` so I added that within my program as well `driver=webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')` But this gave me the same error.
There are multiple chromedrivers with different versions, and thus the only thing I can think of is the chromedriver version installed by buildriver is not compatible the Chrome version on my phone? But outside of this, I don't know why I am receiving this error.

Answer (score 3):

```js
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('androidPackage', 'com.android.chrome')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.quit()
```

Have you tried these options?

source: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started/getting-started---android

Comment: This change nothing. Still got the same error!

Answer (score 1):

try adding required permissions in the buildozer.spec file.